# error AR303000Submit use php - Api Acumatica ERP

Tags: c#, php, api, erp, acumatica

I'm connecting api of Acumatica. Present, i use AR303000Submit function. but it return error

```html
Error #102: View  doesn't exist.
   at PX.Data.PXViewCollection.get_Item(String key)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.FillSearches(String viewName, SyView view, List`1 srchs, List`1 sorts, List`1 descs)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.SelectRows(String viewName, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32 topCount, Boolean bypassInserted, Int32 startRow, Dictionary`2 externalSorts)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.a(SyStep A_0, GrowingTable A_1, SyCommand A_2, PXFilterRow[] A_3, Int32 A_4)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, Command[] commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, Boolean mobile, PXGraph& forceGraph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
   at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I know some question about this object is much but this is old or not update

My code

```
        $AR303000GetSchema = $acumatica->client->AR303000GetSchema(new GetSchema());
        $AR303000GetSchema = $AR303000GetSchema->GetSchemaResult;
        $acumatica->client->AR303000Clear(new Clear());

        $AR303000Submit = new Submit();

        $AR303000Submit->commands = array
        (
            $acumatica->prepareValue("TEST123",            $AR303000GetSchema->CustomerSummary->CustomerID),
            $acumatica->prepareValue("TEST123",     $AR303000GetSchema->CustomerSummary->CustomerName),
            $acumatica->prepareValue('US',              $AR303000GetSchema->GeneralInfoMainAddress->Country),   
            $AR303000GetSchema->Actions->Save
        ); 
        $submit_result = $acumatica->client->AR303000Submit($AR303000Submit);
```

Help me. Thanks

**Update**
I try it at http://forum.acumatica.com/forum/acumatica-reseller-and-isv-community/development-and-customization/740-api-how-to-create-api-project-and-use-it-with-c-php-java?q=php (#3)

```
        $schema = $AR303000GetSchema;

        $cmds = array();

        $cmd = new Value();
        $cmd->Value = "giahoang";
        $cmd->LinkedCommand = $schema->CustomerSummary->CustomerID;
        $soapvar = new \SoapVar($cmd, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Value", "http://www.acumatica.com/typed/");
        array_push($cmds, $soapvar);

        $cmd = new Value();
        $cmd->Value = "giahoang";
        $cmd->LinkedCommand = $schema->CustomerSummary->CustomerName;
        $soapvar = new \SoapVar($cmd, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Value", "http://www.acumatica.com/typed/");
        array_push($cmds, $soapvar);

        $cmd = new Value();
        $cmd->Value = "US";
        $cmd->LinkedCommand = $schema->GeneralInfoMainAddress->Country;
        $soapvar = new \SoapVar($cmd, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Value", "http://www.acumatica.com/typed/");
        array_push($cmds, $soapvar);

        $cmd = new Value();
        $cmd->Value = "hoang@acumatica.com";
        $cmd->LinkedCommand = $schema->GeneralInfoMainContact->Email;
        $soapvar = new \SoapVar($cmd, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Value", "http://www.acumatica.com/typed/");
        array_push($cmds, $soapvar);

        $soapvar = new \SoapVar($schema->Actions->Save, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Action", "http://www.acumatica.com/typed/");
        array_push($cmds, $soapvar);

        $submit_result = $acumatica->client->AR303000Submit(array(array("commands" => $cmds)));
        print_r($submit_result);
```

return error

```html
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: source\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\n   
at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)\n   
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I don't know i was misstake. 
PS: I try C#, it ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's general error, looks like something wrong with your code.

please follow old article 
http://forum.acumatica.com/forum/acumatica-reseller-and-isv-community/development-and-customization/740-api-how-to-create-api-project-and-use-it-with-c-php-java?q=php

also you can take a look general help and info from Acumatica Univeristy there is training quide.

Comment: Thanks srodiovo, i try it but some error at #3 (article's srodionov) System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: source\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\n   at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Do you have a method?

Comment: Sorry, after checked, it run true. Thanks