# Acumatica Submit Error Using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, acumatica

I need your help.

I'm trying to update acumatica customer account using web services and I'm getting an error like this:

> PX.Data.PXException: Error #107: The view doesn't exist.
>   at PX.Data.PXViewCollection.get_Item(String key)
>   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.FillSearches(String viewName, SyView view, List`1 srchs, List`1 sorts, List`1 descs)
>   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.SelectRows(String viewName, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32 topCount, Boolean bypassInserted, Int32 startRow, SyExportContext exportContext)
>   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.a(SyStep A_0, GrowingTable A_1, SyCommand A_2, PXFilterRow[] A_3, Int32 A_4)
>   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
>   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, Command[] commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
>   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, Boolean mobile, PXGraph& forceGraph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
>   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
>   at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)

This is my code:

```
public function update_test()
{

    $client = new AcumaticaGate();
    $client = $client->AcumaticaGate('admin', '123456', 'AR303000', 'http://localhost:100/AcumaticaERP/(W(5))');

    $schema         = $client->Schema->GetSchemaResult;

    $customer       = $schema->CustomerSummary->CustomerID;
    $customer_name  = $schema->CustomerSummary->CustomerName;

    $command = array();
    array_push($command, $client->PrepareValue('TEST', $customer));
    array_push($command, $client->PrepareValue('NAME', $customer_name));

    array_push($command, $schema->Actions->Save);

    $submit = new Submit();
    $submit->commands = $command;

    try
    {
        $submit_result = $client->Client->Submit($submit);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
       print_r($e);
    }   
}
```

Can you guys help me solved this problem? because i've been stuck at this thing for a long time.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working with Acumatica 5.3 or 6.0?

Comment: Have you tried creating a customer with just Test and name in the UI?  My version of Acumatica pops a message about how I need an email address.  Perhaps you don't have enough data elements.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response guys. @RuslanDev I'm using acumatica version 6.00.1384. I already try to add another data elements, but the error keep showing. I just trying another method here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664742/error-ar303000submit-use-php-api-acumatica-erp[/link] but it's not working too. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: @FillGunawan, just wondering what was the reason to not use REST Contract-Based API of Acumatica available with ver. 6?

Comment: @RuslanDev do you have any example or reference how to use Rest Contract-Based API Acumatica using PHP? I have try to search the topic but it's really hard to find.

Comment: @FillGunawan, did you have time to go though I210 Contract-Based Web Services 6.0 class at AcumaticaUniversity.com or AcumaticaOpenUniversity.com ? It's also worth checking what's in Help -> User Guide -> Integration